# get notification when app closed , don't show notification when app is not running

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I using **firebase** and get notification from server when app is running work fine but when close it don't show.

how i do this? i don't know anything about it

how to get start learn it or where i found example from this code.i using every thing from firebase.

for example...

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

just want to write code for this action.

Comment: what you can do is to create a remote service which would run in the background for your app , and then your firebase notifications would be easily recieved


see this example for setting remote service - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Remote_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_An_Android_Studio_Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is official code base from firebase.  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

Comment: i dont know how use it.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is on foreground, you can get notify with firebase panel. But when it's on background or killed, you can't get notify with firebase panel. You have to use server-base-code for it, like php script. And you can get answer from stack as this question is asked before.